# Windows rotated screen and resolution management in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I am currently having hard time dealing with the rotation system of Windows hybrid tablets.

When the screen rotates, the application (playing in fullscreen) is correctly rotated, and change its resolution so as to fit the height of the tablet. Then, when you rotate the screen back in landscape mode, the application keeps the last resolution used when it was in portrait mode. And when I restart the game, the last "broken" resolution is used

[image: Resolution]

Here is a little piece of code I try to make in order to fix the problem. I can't rely on the Screen size nor Screen.orientation (the returned values are incorrect)... The code does not totally work. The result is showed in the image below

```
    private void SetMaxResolution()
    {
        currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;
        maxResolution     = Screen.resolutions[Screen.resolutions.Length - 1];
        currentRatio      = currentResolution.width / ( (float) currentResolution.height );
        maxRatio          = maxResolution.width / ( (float) maxResolution.height );
        screenWidth       = Screen.width;
        screenHeight      = Screen.height;

        if ( Mathf.Abs( currentRatio - maxRatio ) > 0.01f )
        {
            // If I use maxResolution, Unity will try to set the maxResolution everytime when in Portrait mode. Because of this, the frame rate drops and the application is unusable.
            Screen.SetResolution( currentResolution.width, Mathf.RoundToInt( currentResolution.width / maxRatio ), true );
        }
    }
```

[image: Resolution fix]

---

EDIT : I found [this link](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-disable-rotate-screen-utility-by-code.264408/) providing a way to disable portrait mode, but I would like to keep this possibility...

```
    public static void SetScreenOrientationToLandscape()
    {
        SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences( (int) ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE.ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE |
            (int) ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE.ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE_FLIPPED );
    }

    public enum ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE
    {
        ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_NONE = 0x0,
        ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE = 0x1,
        ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT = 0x2,
        ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE_FLIPPED = 0x4,
        ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT_FLIPPED = 0x8
    }
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "User32.dll" )]
    public static extern bool SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences( int value );
```